# Testing a Set Object with RSpec

Tags: ruby, rspec

*I'm new to testing!

Code:

```
class SetTest

  def remove_duplicates(array)
      new_set = Set.new
      array.each {|number| new_set << number}
      new_set
  end

end
```

RSpec:

```
describe SetTest do

  before(:each) do
    @new_set = SetTest.new
  end

  describe '#remove_duplicates' do
    it 'removes duplicates from an array' do
      array = [1,2,3,4,5,5,5,5,5,6,7,8,9,10]
      expect(@new_set.remove_duplicates(array)).to eql([{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}])
    end
  end

end
```

It get the following error:

```
 syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting tASSOC (SyntaxError)...e_duplicates(array)).to eql({1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10})
```

Then, when I just try this:

```
expect(@new_set.remove_duplicates(array)).to eql([1])
```

I get:

```
expected: [1]
got: #<Set: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}>
```

Any idea how I can go about testing this?

*Note: I'm aware I can just use .uniq! to remove duplicates from the array. I am simply using this for an example on how to test Set objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this test you're comparing a Set object to an Array (with a misformed Hash inside of it).

```
expect(@new_set.remove_duplicates(array)).to eql([{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}])
```

You need to create a new set including 1..10 inside of it and compare those.

new_set = (1..10).to_set

and change your expectation

expect(@new_set.remove_duplicates(array)).to eq new_set

You can also test the length of the set to ensure it only contains the expected number of elements.

```
expect(@new_set.remove_duplicates(array).length).to eq 10
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed. Appreciate it!